# YII - Render another view into component view

Tags: yii, components, render

I have a component with **comment** name. this component has a view file with `test.php` name.

I would like to render another view file in test.php. How I can do this?

file map:

```
component/
  |
  comment.php
  view/
     |_
       test.php
       another.php
```

Comment: I think you dont need a component to do that. You need a widget.

Comment: If you have to do something like this, your overall component design is questionable. So maybe you should rather reconsider your approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it this way to have multiple views.

```
$this->render('view1', array('model' => $model));

// then, inside the view you can render a subview like this:
$this->renderPartial('view2', array('model' => $model));
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: this is the right answer, you need to make sure that another.php is in the right place.

Comment: @user1702468 `comment` can not find `another.php` template

Comment: When you render one view, is it working ?  Can you please copy and past your code block so it will be easy to help.